# "Rate limit error" with vimeo API

Tags: vimeo

In my application , I have used Vimeo API. Sometimes I get **Rate Limit Exceed** error.

My question is that:

1. Is it App specific?( requests made per app irrespective of any no. of devices that are using it)" OR
2. Is it device specific? Suppose two devices have this app and it is possible that one gets this error but the other does not).

In my case, if I made many requests of different kinds and this error occurred. Immediately I installed this app on another device. The other one also start getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is app specific for unauthenticated calls if it crosses its daily limit. Like i was getting this error only when if i searched any videos but not when accessing my private videos. And for authenticated calls if you crosses its daily limit then it will be device specific. For more details: https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting